# Prometheus or Cloudwatch to monitor AWS infrastructure metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana

I want to monitor all my AWS resources (EC2, S3, Lambda, etc) using a Grafana dashboard in real time.
If I use Cloudwatch, I'd have to create custom metrics and export them to Grafana (because the out-of-the-box CloudWatch metrics are not enough).
However, I want to use Prometheus. So, is there a way to use Prometheus to collect metrics of all my AWS resources without having to install an Agent inside each resource? Can I set custom metrics directly on Prometheus (for example, number of running EC2 or memory utilization)?

I already have a Grafana and Prometheus servers running on my setup.

Comment: You need to install node exporter on all the servers that you want to monitor. These will collect metrics for promethues. After that grafana will use promethues as data source & show dashboards for it. There are many dashboards on grafana community for this. 

Check this link for more details - https://dev.to/aws-builders/monitoring-prometheus-and-grafana-on-aws-548h

Comment: @CloudWanderer but node exporter is only for EC2 Linux machines. OP wants to monitor also resources, where any agent/exporter can't be running, e. g. S3

Comment: Yes. For windows, there is wmi exporter. For S3 or other AWS resources, there are some dashboards in grafana that can be used. These need role based permission to acces & show details.

Answer (score 0):

Generally: There is no way to do that, because you need something (agent, exporter) what will push or expose metrics for Prometheus.

IMHO the best way is to replicate existing metrics from the CloudWatch with some CloudWatch exporter (e.g. [YACE](https://github.com/nerdswords/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter)) to Prometheus. Then you can "calculate" some your custom metrics (e.g. number of running EC2) based on these CloudWatch metrics in Prometheus. But you will need agent/exporter for the rest of custom metrics. I would incorporate also OTEL collector (e.g. [ADOT Collector](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector)), to be ready for brighter OTEL future.